# heatmap-esque plot for mouse clicking data

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I have the x and y coordinates for a whole bunch of mouse clicks. A simple scatterplot of these coordinates is below.

[image]

As you can see, obviously, there seems to be 3 areas where the clicks are relatively more concentrated. I would like to plot these clicks in a way that reflects the relative concentration of the clicks - e.g., circles in an area with a high concentration of clicks are relatively larger or have darker colors. Obviously a simple scatterplot does not show that. I tried following the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004063/creating-a-heat-map-from-x-y-corrdinates-in-r/5004637#5004637), but result is not what I want.

So any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of `kde2d` from the `MASS` package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any of these work for you?

```
## scatter
plot(quakes$long, quakes$lat)
```

[image]

```
library(hexbin)
plot(hexbin(quakes$long, quakes$lat))
```

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(quakes, aes(x = long, y = lat)) + stat_density2d(aes(alpha = ..level..), geom = "polygon")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(quakes, aes(x = long, y = lat)) + stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "tile", contour = FALSE)
```

[image]

```
library(MASS)
filled.contour(kde2d(quakes$long, quakes$lat))
```

[image]

Comment: The 3rd option looks great. With the last option, which is essentially what the linked post included in my question did, I seem to have trouble getting the desired colors... probably it has to do with my chosen bandwidth.

Comment: @Alex It should be pretty easy to change the colors of the second  `ggplot` option by adding `scale_fill_continuous(low = "white", high = "black")` or whatever colors you want